# How to: Hide menu items based on vuetify breakpoint

Tags: vue.js, pug, vuetify.js

I am working on a Vue.js project and I need to figure out How to hide these menu items when this breakpoint is active. `$vuetify.breakpoint.sm`  The following code currently shows this menu item when this breakpoint is active / the screen is small.

```js
 div(v-show="$vuetify.breakpoint.sm").mobileCta
        a(@click="showMobileMenu = !showMobileMenu").mobileCta__link
          v-icon(v-if="!showMobileMenu").mobileCta__link__icon menu
          v-icon(v-if="showMobileMenu").mobileCta__link__icon close
```

How can I make the code below function the same? I am looking to HIDE these links when the  `$vuetify.breakpoint.sm` is active.

```js
      template(v-if="isDeveloperRoute" v-show="!$vuetify.breakpoint.sm")
            RiseLink(to="/creators#sdks").developers SDKs
            RiseLink(to="/creators#useCases").useCases Use Cases
            RiseLink(to="/creators/support").support Support
            RiseLink(:to="links.developerLogin").login Login
            RiseLink(:to="links.developerGetStarted").getStarted Create Studio Account
          template(v-else-if="isParentRoute" v-show="!$vuetify.breakpoint.sm")
            RiseLink(to="/parents").parents Parents Home
            //- RiseLink(to="/parents#featuredApp" ).featuredApp Featured App
            RiseLink(to="/parents#faqs").faqs FAQs
            RiseLink(to="/parents/support").support Support
            //- RiseLink(:to="links.login").login Login
            //- RiseLink(:to="links.getStarted").getStarted Get Started
          template(v-else v-show="!$vuetify.breakpoint.sm")
            RiseLink(to="/creators").forDevelopers For Creators
            RiseLink(to="/parents").forParents For Parents
            RiseLink(to="/contact").contactUs Contact Us
```

Comment: try $vuetify.breakpoint.smOnly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `v-show="!$vuetify.breakpoint.xs"`

Answer (score 3):

you can use vuetify css classes like:

hidden-lg-only

hidden-md-and-up, hidden-md-only, hidden-md-and-down

hidden-sm-and-up, hidden-sm-only, hidden-sm-and-down

hidden-xs-only